# Anchor tag in Drop down

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, anchor

I was researching how to create a drop down menu that once an option is selected, rather than jump to a new page, you scroll down the page via an anchor tag, but I can't quire figure it out.

My logic so far is to set the dropdown to a variable.  Take that variable and onchange, compare it to it's current position and as long as the position isn't "0" try to make it follow the anchor link, just as if I was making it load a new page.  Can someone help me with what I'm missing?

HTML:

```
<select name="dropDown" id="dropDown">
<option value="one"><a href="#heading1">one</a></option>
<option value="two"><a href="#heading2">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
</select>


<p id="heading1"><a name="heading1">Heading one</a></p>

<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br    /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />

<p id="heading2"><a name="heading2">Heading 2</a></p>
```

JS:

```
var dropDownValue = document.getElementById("dropDown");

dropDownValue.onchange = function()
{
if(this.selectedIndex !== 0)
{
    window.location.href=this.value;
}
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example.

**P.S:** Avoid `anchor` inside `option`.

```js
var dropDownValue = document.getElementById("dropDown");

dropDownValue.onchange = function() {
  if (this.selectedIndex !== 0) {
    window.location.href = this.value;
  }
};
```

```css
p {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<select name="dropDown" id="dropDown">
  <option value="#heading1">one</option>
  <option value="#heading2">two</option>
  <option value="#heading3">three</option>
</select>

<p id="heading1"><a name="heading1">Heading one</a>
</p>
<p id="heading2"><a name="heading2">Heading two</a>
</p>
<p id="heading3"><a name="heading3">Heading three</a>
```

Comment: Would there be an easy way to make the scroll smooth using vanilla js?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot put anchor tags into a `<select>` element. But the problem I think you are having is that you are using `window.location.href` when you should be using `window.location.hash`.

I've created this fiddle that maintains the anchor tag but uses hash. I had to update the value of `"value="` to match the `id` where you want the browser to scroll to.

https://jsfiddle.net/jqcdyv2b/

Comment: Ah okay I see. But this is functioning with anchor tags in the select, should it not be?

Comment: I would not add them in because they aren't being used. It changes because of the JS code and the `value` on the option element. Removing the `<a>` tags will not break anything in this case. Here is an updated version (and removed the alert): https://jsfiddle.net/jqcdyv2b/1/

Comment: You also don't need the `<a>` tags in your `<p>` elements. The `href` or `hash` value works off of the `id` of an element.

Comment: Would there be an easy way to make the scroll smooth using vanilla js?

Answer (score 0):

I have some suggestion.

**Method 1:** You can use dropdown navigation

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/

**Method 2:** You can also use select2.js

https://select2.org/